# MongoDB different result of aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I have this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$PATIENT_ID", 
      MASS: { $max: "$max_field" }
    }
  }
]);
```

The result of this query is:

```
{ "_id" : "TCGA-A2-A0YD", "mass" : 0.994683301742671 }
{ "_id" : "TCGA-A2-A3XX", "mass" : 0.993455527786917 }
```

I have this second query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "TCGA-A2-A3XX",
      MASS: { $max: "$max_field" }
    }
  }
]);
```

The result of this second query is:

```
{ "_id" : "TCGA-A2-A3XX", "mass" : 0.994683301742671 }
```

Why?
 I expected another value for this id `TCGA-A2-A3XX`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are grouping all documents by the constant `"TCGA-A2-A3XX"` and therefore you get a single group with that ID and calculate the maximum of the field from all documents.
I guess you want to add a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage to your pipeline to filter for your specific patient.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: {
      PATIENT_ID: "TCGA-A2-A3XX"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$PATIENT_ID",
      MASS: { $max: "$max_field" }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know why in the first case I obtain : TCGA-A2-A3XX,  0.993455527786917 and in the second case I obtain TCGA-A2-A3XX 0.994683301742671

Comment: Because in the first case you use "$PATIENT_ID" which refers to the documents' field "PATIENT_ID" and so you group by the values of that field. In the other case you group by the constant which will always result in a single group.

Comment: Ok, but TCGA-A2-A3XX is one value of PATIENT_ID field

Comment: Maybe it helps to understand it if you try $group: {_id : "foobar" ... -> Same result

Comment: You just tell the aggregation pipeline to group all documents by the constant and because it is a constant (not a path to a document field), there is built a single group with all documents and for this group with all docs (including the one with 0.994683301742671) you calculate the maximum

Comment: ok, I understand thanks. so for insert where clause? WHERE PATIENT_ID = TCGA-A2-A3XX ?

Comment: I updated my answer. I can't test it for you 100% bc I only can guess what the documents look like but I hope it works - otherwise please share some sample documents